# What is the reason for this prolonged thread wait when trying to connect with redis with incorrect ip via jedis connector?

Tags: java, threadpool, jedis, getresource

I'm connecting redis with the help of `jedis` connector. I have my redis ip value in a properties file and would be initialised with the help of `jedis`. The thread which executes `redis.get` is undergoing prolonged wait. Here is a sample thread dump

```
"pool-5-thread-999" #1119 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa4307ff800 nid=0x4a23 waiting on condition [0x00007fa3d581c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000a6a006b8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:524)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:438)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84)
    at com.xyz.redis.MyRedisClient.getJedis(MyRedisClient.java:53)
    at com.xyz.redis.MyRedisClient.getDataFromRedis(MyRedisClient.java:99)
```

What does this exception really mean?

This is the redis get `getDataFromRedis` method which is used to fetch data from redis.

```
public static String getDataFromRedis(String key) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Entering into get data from redis : "+key);
        Jedis jedisCon = null; 
        try {
            jedisCon = getJedis();
            jedisCon.select(1);
            return jedisCon.get(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while getting data from redis : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jedisCon != null) {
                returnJedis(jedisCon);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is the sample `getJedis()` code snippet

```
private static Jedis getJedis() {
        if (pool == null) {
            try{
                initRedisClient();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Exception while Initializing RedisClient" + ex);    
            }
        }
        return pool.getResource();
    }
```

And here is the initialisation part

```
public static void initRedisClient() throws Exception {
    try {
       String propertiesFilePath = "/Users/Ritchie/conf/redis.properties";
       Properties redisProps = MyUtils.loadProperties(propertiesFilePath);
       JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(redisProps.getProperty("redisserver"));      
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Thus the occurred exception is : "+ex);
    }
```

So, When I try to `getResource()` from the pool with `pool.getResource()` with incorrect ip the pool is in prolonged wait state.

Why the thread goes to prolonged wait when trying to get resource from the pool which is registered with incorrect ip the thread goes to prolonged wait why?

Answer (score 1):

The Jedis source code for [JedisPool](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisPool.java#L33) and [Connection](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Connection.java#L182) indicates that the 'IP address' you provide is actually used to do a host lookup **by name**. In case the host is not present and available in your LAN, there is a timeout of 15 seconds or more for this lookup.

Try using an 'invalid' IP address from a machine in your LAN that has no REDIS server running. You should not see this prolonged timeout now.